# What does "$z\in\Bbb{C}\setminus\{i,-2\}$" mean?

Tags: complex-numbers, notation

What does "$z\in\Bbb{C}\setminus\{i,-2\}$" (as highlighted in yellow below) mean?

[image]

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Please don't use pictures.

Comment: What happens if $z=i,-2$? This is a detail telling you where the function is defined

Comment: Look at the section on “relative complement” (also called “set difference”) here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Complement_(set_theory)

Comment: That simply means that $z$ can be any complex number except $i$ and $-2$ since in those cases we would divide by $0$.

Answer (score 5):

If you have two sets, $A$ and $B$, then $A \backslash B$. The elements of this new set are all elements that belong to $A$ but don't belong to $B$: $$x \in A \backslash B \iff x\in A \wedge x \notin B$$

So the set $\mathbb C \backslash\{i, -2\}$ is the set of all complex numbers without $i$ and $-2$.